# Package .NETStandard Project with Build Targets

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a .NET Standard class library that includes an MSBuild Task that I would like to add as a dependency to downstream projects.

Basic structure of the project would be

- my-proj.csproj

  - build

    - my-proj.targets
  - MyCustomTask.cs

I've set the project properties to "Generate NuGet Package on Build" and the documentation states that simply using the "build" directory convention should be enough to place the targets file in the build directory of the generated package.

However, on build all the nuget package contains is the project assembly.  How can I configure my project so that the targets file is included in the package as a "build" artefact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the items to be packed and specify a custom package path by updating the item inside the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="build\**" Pack="true" PackagePath="\build" />
  <None Update="buildCrossTargeting\**" Pack="true" PackagePath="\buildCrossTargeting" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I actually set the PackagePath to \ as the build process uses the project relative path for items